# maven plugin for eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to install maven plugin on eclipse 3.7
I want separate menu items "update dependencies" and "update project configuration" at maven context menu, but now I have common menu item "update project"
so where I can find needed maven version?

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Update Dependencies` and `Update Configuration` actions and corresponding dialogs are collapsed into single "Update Project" action since [m2e 1.1M5](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-dev/msg00906.html) because of [this request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367547) .

So , using the version before `1.1 M5 version` should bring you back the separate context meun items that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Those two menu items were replaced by the one which you have mentioned. So you have to live with it (or install an older version of m2e). I like this new option in my experience it runs more stable.

Comment: I suspect there is version 1.x. but where I can find it? all links don't wirk... I can't find working one. can you help, please?

Comment: @user2346224 you can find older versions of m2e [here](https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/). I don't know in which version the menu items were replaced